# Updating ListBox causes delay

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, delay, itemssource

I want to display a ListBox with around 10 items in it. Every time I update it by adding an item to a `List` it causes a little but noticeable delay and the UI freezes for a little while. I also tried using an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List` as the `ItemsSource`, which didn't fix the problem.

My ListBox must update really fast, so I really need your help, please! :)

Here is some code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    //private List<Word> Words = new List<Word>();
    ObservableCollection<Word> Words = new ObservableCollection<Word>();

    // Konstruktor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.ItemsSource = Words;

        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Words.Add(new Word(j.ToString()));
        }
    }
}

public class Word
{
    public String sWord { get; set; }

    public Word(String word)
    {
        this.sWord = word;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox1">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Button Content="{Binding sWord}" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: show your DataTemplate / class which is being displayed in the list. If you have too many converters / logic happening, you'll have bad perf.

Comment: I updated the post. It really isn't much code.

Comment: How are you adding the items?

Comment: Just by adding an item to the list: `Words.Add(new Word("hello"));`

Comment: Can you provide more code to illustrate the way you are adding items to the ObservableCollection ?
To optimize your ListBox, you can create the DataTemplate in the App.xaml.

Comment: your actual logic looks simple, are you doing a bunch before/after you add the Word on the UI thread?

Comment: I tried the whole thing on a fresh project. So no, I don't perform any actions before adding items to the List/ObservableCollection. I added the whole code to my first post.
Can you further explain how to create the DataTemplate inside the App.xaml, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. To fix the delay I am now using a StackPanel instead of a ListBox and add my Buttons in the following way:

```
StackPanel1.Children.Add(new Button()
{
    Content             = "Hello World",
    BorderBrush         = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent),
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
});
```

You can clear the StackPanel with

```
StackPanel1.Children.Clear();
```

Adding a Click event to the buttons works like this

```
foreach (Button btn in StackPanel1.Children)
{
    btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Button_Click);
}
```

Very easy and much much faster!